# Hide the tick in Salesforce Path LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there a way to not show the tick mark when a stage is completed in a lightning path?
I don't want the user to hover over the tick to find out what stage is complete. I want it to be shown directly.

Default/ Current Behaviour: the user has to hover over the tick mark on the completed stage to see the name of the stage.
[image]

But I want to not show the tick mark and the hover and directly show the name of the completed stage like this:
[image]

I tried looking up the the CSS styles in https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/path/#site-main-content but did not find anything to address my need. any pointers please.

Answer (score 1):

The code indicating that a check should be displayed when complete is in the link you posted,

```
<li class="slds-path__item slds-is-complete" role="presentation">
          <a aria-selected="false" class="slds-path__link" href="#" id="path-6" role="option" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="slds-path__stage">
              <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"></use>
              </svg>
              <span class="slds-assistive-text">Stage Complete</span>
            </span>
            <span class="slds-path__title">Contacted</span>
          </a>
        </li>
```

if you replace/remove the check icon, it should no longer be displayed when completed.

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the variant attribute on the lightning:path component.

<lightning:path  variant="linear"> will show tick marks

where as

<lightning:path  variant="non-linear"> will show the stage name

Comment: Gautam could you please clarify as how you are trying to this? From your question it does not seem that your are trying to do this from SLDS blueprints.

Comment: hey Rajiv, I am using the standard <lightning-progress-indicator> LWC component for this and was looking for properties that can help me achieve what I am after. Your answer works well for Aura but I did not find a similar one for LWC. variant attribute in LWC allows only two values, base or shaded.